# Why is my object being added to both collections?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, javascript-framework, ember-data

Please reference the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VkKX2/138/ (be sure to have your console open)

**TL;DR;** I have 2 hasMany collections, and when I add a new model to one collection, it also gets added to the other collection.

SO requires code, so here's a very high-level summary:

```
var foo = App.FooModel.find(101);
var bar = App.BarModel.find(204);

foo.get('collection2').addObject( bar );
foo.get('collection1').contains( bar ); // yields true
```

**Question:** Why is my object being added to *both* collections!?

Comment: are you sure you're not feeding the prototype of the collections wrongly? it would then add the values to both collections indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just** as I posted this, I realized the problem:

When I generate my summary, I want to loop through all objects in *either* collection:

```
var bars = foo.get('collection1').addObjects( foo.get( 'collection2' )).uniq();
```

This has the unrealized effect of adding collection2 to the *reference* of collection1 and not just to the resultant `bar` variable. By changing the code to this, the problem is solved:

```
var bars = foo.get('collection1').toArray().addObjects( foo.get( 'collection2' )).uniq();
```